# Using gson to parse jsonarray and jsonobject

Tags: arrays, gson, json

a login api when success return:

```
{"status":0,"data":{userid:1,username:"abc"},"msg":"login sucess"}
```

but when error server return:

```
{"status":0,"data":[],"msg":"login failure！"}
```

how to define a object, then use gson to parse the data field!
thanks.

Comment: when success the status code is 1. when error the status code is 0;

Answer (score 0):

Is it **`json`** or **`gson`**? For example your response is on this variable `$response;`

You can try:

```
<?php
$response = '{"status":0,"data":{userid:1,username:"abc"},"msg":"login sucess"}';

// $response = '{"status":0,"data":[],"msg":"login failure！"}';

$response = json_decode($response);
if(empty($response->data){
    echo $response->msg;
}

// print_r($response); //you can try to print_r $response here
// if have data to login, do what you want
```

Comment: using java language and the json lib google gson to parse

Comment: so you can call the response with fromJson(response); to get the data